# Unmounting proc file system

Tags: linux, kernel, procfs

As far as I know proc file system is a virtual file system. Is there any way to unmount the proc file system and even if I do that what will be the consequences after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check (as root) who is using a mounted filesystem like so:

```
fuser -m /proc
```

Typically, your box will not be very usable if you kill all the processes using /proc. Otherwise, there is no law saying it has to be mounted, beyond all and sundry developer assuming that it is.

Comment: Actually, you can even do "fuser -mk /proc" to kill them.

Answer (score 1):

`umount` will work like on any other file system (same conditions for a filesystem to be unmonted). You can expect a whole lot of this to stop working as soon as you do that though (including very simple utilities like `ps`).

Comment: I think there is no command called **unmount**. There is only a command called **umount**

Comment: Not always. A process that has hung in "D" state (during an I/O syscall essentially) cannot be killed. If you have a process like that hung on /proc, you won't be able to unmount it. Note that you should not unmount /proc anyway.